# Refreshing a php page after submit button - PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, page-refresh

I have a page that needs to be constantly refreshed multiple times a minute. The page has is a echo'd php table. [image: Preivew]

The page loads perfectly fine, all is good, I have used the META tag HTML, I have used the header tag with the refresh function in PHP... and yet a problem arises :

When I hit Start Session button the refresh stops. And the table bellow does does not get updated. So then I have to manually refresh the page. This is not the desired affect. Can some one explain to me how to refresh a page continually.

Edit 1:

Code that makes the include of the session start

```
foreach($result as $row)
    {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <a href=student.php?anum=" . $row['anum'] . " target='_blank'>" .$row['anum'] . " </a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['first'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['last'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['why'] . "</td>";  
  echo "<td>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['additional_req'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['signintime'] . "</td>";
  echo "
        <td>    <form action='counselor.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' method='post' target='_new'>
                    <select name='namedrop'>
                        <option value=''>Counselor Name</option> 
                        <option value='Admin-John'>Admin - John</option>
                        <option value='Admin-Christine'>Admin - Christine</option>
                        <option value='Admin-Dawne'>Admin - Dawne</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Cherie'>Counselor - Cherie</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Tootie'>Counselor - Tootie</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Debbie'>Counselor - Debbi</option>
                        <option value='FrontDesk-Delores'>Front Desk - Delores</option>
                        <option value='FrontDesk-Kiana'>Front Desk - Kiana</option>
                    </select>
            </td>

            <td> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Start Session'></td>
            </form> </td>";
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code that you use to display the "Start Session" buttons?

Comment: Thank you.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to refresh the page when you click "Start Session", then you can edit your submit button to have this onClick listener.  It should refresh the page.

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Start Session' onClick="window.location.reload()" />
```

Comment: Right I have done that, however when I hit the start session button the page stops resetting. I am inputting a form and then the page stops refreshing period.

Comment: Did not work. I tried this at the end of my code : $page = "inoffice.php";
$sec = "10";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page"); and still nothing .

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use Javascript to achieve the desired effect? I don't know enough about what you're doing to determine whether that would clear your changes or not (my assumption here is: no).

If you are able to use Javascript, you could write a simple function which refreshes the page on an interval.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">
```

or

```
<form action="thispage.php" method="post">
```

Comment: What will form action have to do with anything? My form action leads to the script with my input statements. What I am confused about is actually refreshing the page after the form is submitted.

Comment: The form action is the page that you are redirected to when you submit that form.  If the action is the current page, it gives your desired "refresh" effect.

Comment: right but the form action is another page that is a an actual url page that is needed. not just a script. its an open url redirect.